# Sylius Grid Bundle over Api Response

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have several projects (on local / Amazon EC2) for various purposes.

The one on EC2 hold the main DB and is accessible through an API, exposing most of my Resources.

I need to display on ALL of my instances Grids to interact with these resources.

Easy on the EC2, but can't find a way with SyliusGridBundle to Map to an Api response.

Is it even possible ?